# How can I remove the logo from title and other pages in uoy-beamer theme?

Tags: beamer

Got the theme from GitHub [uoy-beamer](https://github.com/nitrogl/uoy-beamer). I would like to remove the logo from the title page as well as other pages - for both the light and dark themes.(as shown in the image). How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Because it's an unofficial beamer style, maybe it's better to open a issue on the repo and ask the author.

Comment: Look at the theme code and read the beamer mnaual.  Better yet, keep searching for a better theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your code as follows (using `uoy-example.tex` included in the distribution)

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[t,compress,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{uoy-beamer} % no options or darktheme <<<<<
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0cm, width=0cm]{uoy-tab}{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0cm, width=0cm]{uoy-tab-institute}{} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pgfdeclareimage{bottomtitledarktheme}{} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{listings}

....
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you ! works perfectly